# Adding/removing class to parent element while clicking on checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, input

I have simple list with `<input type='checkbox'>` inside every `li`. Few of them are `checked` and other not

```
<ul>
<li><input type='checkbox' checked></li>
<li><input type='checkbox'></li>
<li><input type='checkbox' checked></li>
<li><input type='checkbox'></li>
</ul>
```

How can I add class `.transparent` to those `li` that contains `<input type='checkbox'>` that is not checked and remove this class when user will mark `<input type='checkbox'>` as `checked`?

The main problem is that I want to add/remove this class (1) when page is loading and (2) change it later while user will click something on my list.

Comment: Made an edit... had the boxes carry the class `transparent ` in reverse I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// (1) when page is loading
   $("li").each(function(index) {    if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
         $(this).addClass('transparent');
     }
   });
   
});


//(2) change it later while user will click something on my list.


$(document).on('change',"ul li input[type=checkbox]",function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('transparent');
});
```

```css
.transparent{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><input type='checkbox' checked></li>
<li><input type='checkbox'></li>
<li><input type='checkbox' checked></li>
<li><input type='checkbox'></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly (almost) what I need!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with some JavaScript:

```js
function formatCheckboxes(){
  jQuery('li').each(function( index ) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('transparent');
    jQuery(this).has('input:checked').removeClass('transparent');
  });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  formatCheckboxes();
});
jQuery(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]', function(){ 
  formatCheckboxes(); 
});
```

```css
.transparent{
  opacity:0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><input type='checkbox' checked></li>
<li><input type='checkbox'></li>
<li><input type='checkbox' checked></li>
<li><input type='checkbox'></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop thru each checkboxes and check whether they are checked/unchecked and based on that add `transparent` class to the parent `li`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('transparent');
  });
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('transparent');
});
```

```css
.transparent {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type='checkbox' checked></li>
  <li><input type='checkbox'></li>
  <li><input type='checkbox' checked></li>
  <li><input type='checkbox'></li>
</ul>
```